# Outputting text above user input with cout in separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, io

I'm running two threads in a program. One thread sends seconds elapsed to cout every second and the other thread runs a while loop that uses getline and cin to get input from the user in a sort of shell or command line.

My issue is that whenever something is sent to cout while the user is typing something it ends up on top of whatever the user has just typed and it ends up looking messy like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZOCc.png).

Is there any way to move what the user is typing a line down whenever something is sent to cout? Or maybe some alternative io that does this?

I would rather the output look more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPjGL.png)

Here's some extra details and some code:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using std::thread;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

void loop(bool &running)
{
    int secondsElapsed = 0;
    while (running)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        secondsElapsed++;
        cout << std::to_string(secondsPassed) << " Seconds Passed\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    //STARTING OTHER THREAD RIGHT AWAY
    bool running = true;                    
    std::thread t(loop, std::ref(running));

    string param;
    string currentLine;
    vector<string> params;

    while (true)
    {
        //PARSING USER INPUT FOR EVALUATION
        params.clear();

        getline(cin, currentLine);

        std::stringstream currentLineStream(currentLine);

        //CHECKING SIZE OF USER INPUT TO SEE IF THERE IS ANY
        if (currentLineStream.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0)
        {
            while (getline(currentLineStream, param, ' '))
            {
                params.push_back(param);
            }

            //CAPITALISING FIRST PARAMETER TO MAKE EVALUATION EASIER
            boost::to_upper(params[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            params.push_back("");
        }
        //FINISHED PARSING INPUT, EVALUATING

        if (params[0] == "STOP")
        {
            running = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unknown Command, help menu not implemented yet sorry\n";
        }

    }         //END OF USER INPUT LOOP

    t.join(); //WAITING FOR OTHER THREAD TO FINISH
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not with standard C++. You have to use some OS API. On linux you could use curses for that.

Comment: Do you know anything that would work for windows? I am on windows using MinGW 7.1.0 right now btw

Comment: No, I don't. But I am shure there is some API in windows to do that.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, what you could achieve though is to have two separate command prompts, one that prints the seconds and the other one that reads the input, you would have to reassign the input and output std streams for both threads and initialize a new window. I cannot figure out in my head everything happening all in one window.

Comment: if you want something curses like for windows, there is always [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/)